# Java LibGDX Moving to Touch Position on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm using this code but somethings aren't perfect. It's working but not smooth. First it goes touchX and then goes touchY. But I want this at the same time. I tried different codes but didn't work. How can I fix it? What's the problem?

```
package com.anil.game1;
import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Rectangle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
public class Game1 extends ApplicationAdapter {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Texture player1Texture;
    private Rectangle player1Rectangle;
    private Vector3 touchPos;
    @Override
    public void create () {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(480, 800);
        player1Texture = new Texture("Player1.png");
        player1Rectangle = new Rectangle();
        player1Rectangle.set(240, 0, 64, 64);
        touchPos = new Vector3();
    }
    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            touchPos.set(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(touchPos);
            //player1Rectangle.setPosition(new Vector2(touchPos.x, touchPos.y));
        }
        if (touchPos.x > player1Rectangle.x)
            player1Rectangle.x += 5;
        else
            player1Rectangle.x -= 5;
        if (touchPos.y > player1Rectangle.y)
            player1Rectangle.y += 5;
        else
            player1Rectangle.y -= 5;
        batch.draw(player1Texture, player1Rectangle.x - 32, player1Rectangle.y - 32);
        batch.end();
    }
    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        batch.dispose();
        player1Texture.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this section:

```
    if (touchPos.x > player1Rectangle.x)
        player1Rectangle.x += 5;
    else
        player1Rectangle.x -= 5;
    if (touchPos.y > player1Rectangle.y)
        player1Rectangle.y += 5;
    else
        player1Rectangle.y -= 5;
```

You are forcing the rectangle to always move in the X and Y directions by a set amount. It's never allowed to just sit still or slow down. Also, you probably don't want to be handling X and Y separately, because then its speed will be slower in the cardinal directions and faster in the diagonal directions, which would look weird. And finally, you need to work with speed and time to keep a stable movement speed.

So first of all, define a speed for your object. Also, you're going to want a Vector2 handy for calculations.

```
private static final float SPEED = 300f; //world units per second
private final Vector2 tmp = new Vector2();
```

Now after you have calculated touch position, you want to figure out what direction to move in, and how far to move along that direction. So right after your `isTouched` block:

```
//how far the player can move this frame (distance = speed * time):
float maxDistance = SPEED * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

//a vector from the player to the touch point:
tmp.set(touchPos.x, touchPos.y).sub(player1Rectangle.x, player1Rectangle.y); 

if (tmp.len() <= maxDistance) {// close enough to just set the player at the target
    player1Rectangle.x = touchPos.x;
    player1Rectangle.y = touchPos.y;
} else { // need to move along the vector toward the target
    tmp.nor().scl(maxDistance); //reduce vector length to the distance traveled this frame
    player1Rectangle.x += tmp.x; //move rectangle by the vector length
    player1Rectangle.y += tmp.y;
}
```

Comment: Implement an InputListener and move your code there. You can distinguish between fingers with the pointer parameter that's provided.

Comment: I used for loop to do multi touch but two of players' speed is not same. Player1 is more quick than player2. Can you explain a bit about InputListener? I hope you know what I mean. Thanks... How can I use InputProcessor for this code?

Comment: What is the problem at this code? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d5058eec3168234b8571d709566d182

Comment: You are moving the player regardless of whether the corresponding finger is down. So player 1 moves 20 times a frame, player 2 moves 19 times a frame, etc. Look at your if statements closely. InputProcessors are explained in the documentation. Pointless for me to copy paste that information here.

Comment: How can i fix? If necessary , i can create new question?

Comment: Yes, no way to fit answer in these comments.

Comment: Can you help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39086984/java-libgdx-multi-touch-movement